# Why did the Kafka stream fail to produce data after a long time?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

KafkaStream failed to produce data after a long time. (Exceeding the set expiration time)

Even KafkaStream was dead after logging error message.

Exception is below:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeFailWithError(TransactionManager.java:784)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.beginAbort(TransactionManager.java:229)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.abortTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:660)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.closeSuspended(StreamTask.java:493)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.close(StreamTask.java:553)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.close(AssignedTasks.java:405)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.shutdown(TaskManager.java:260)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.completeShutdown(StreamThread.java:1111)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:730)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error in AddOffsetsToTxnResponse: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$AddOffsetsToTxnHandler.handleResponse(TransactionManager.java:1237)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnRequestHandler.onComplete(TransactionManager.java:907)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:101)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:482)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:474)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Version:

1. Kafka Broker: 2.0.0
2. kafka-clients: 1.1.1
3. kafka-streams: 1.1.1

(Broker and Producer) Options are all default:

1. TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG
2. transactional.id.expiration.ms
3. transaction.max.timeout.ms

Code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
properties.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.stream("from", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.String()))
       .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println(value))
       .to("to", Produced.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.String()), (key, value, numPartitions) -> key % numPartitions));

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(bulider.build(), properties);
stream.start();
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem could be. Can you reliably reproduce the issue? If yes, please open a bug report. Do you get the same problem with newer versions of Kafka Streams?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes, I can. Also, Every kafka(v1.1.0 ~ v.2.1.0) stream runs same.
it happens if producer doesn't put the data longer than the set time(transactional.id.expiration.ms).

Comment: Well. If the timeout is hit, it's expected that it fails. Try to increase the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it seems there are a couple of unknown issues here:

1. Inside producer, we do not specially handle `INVALID_PRODUCER_ID_MAPPING` in `AddOffsetsToTxnHandler#handleResponse`, this cased a fatal error with KafkaException to be thrown.
2. Inside streams, we swallow ProducerFencedException but due to 1) a fatal KafkaException is thrown, causing it to go and die directly.

The behavior of 1) is by-design, but I admit it indeed has a few issues as an after-thought:

a. Generally speaking, producer fenced cases, including `INVALID_PRODUCER_ID_MAPPING` should be better handled than 1) above. This is being addressed as https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-360%3A+Improve+handling+of+unknown+producer

b. Txn Producer should have a better distinguishment between "fatal" and non-fatal errors, where the latter should be handled internally than ever handed over to the caller. One quick thought is that, besides producer-fenced error, all other errors we have designed so far should all treated as non-fatal and hence be handled internally.